# separate chart for individual name in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, charts

```
Name  | date         | Val1 | Val2
First |03.05.2018    |  1   |  0  
First | 04.05.2018   |  0   | -1 
First | 05.05.2018   |  -1  |  1     
Second| 04.05.2018   |  0   | -1 
Second| 05.05.2018   |  -1  |   1
```

[image]

The aboveimage is the data I get from a dataset in SSRS. Now I want to create a report with a line chart for each name. The line chart should show the changes in Value1 and Value 2 for each date. I am lost and could you guys point mei n the right direction ?

Sample Graph
[image]

Comment: A sample image with a line chart for one name eg. first would help

Comment: Attached the sample graph @niktrs

Comment: I am still trying to figure out where to start.